# How to run script as a Windows XP service?

Tags: windows-xp, ruby

I want to run my ruby web server as a **Windows XP service**.

Somebody can advice how to do that?

---

I changed (removed the word ruby) the title so more people can find the answer. It will work for any kind of script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am editing a document I created and published to the web for another difficult problem, and adapting it to your question. I cannot be 100% sure that the Resource Kit tools will work with XP, but I believe they probably will.

1) Create a batch file to run your script and start your Ruby server. To be frank, I don't have enough info to tell you how to do that. Copy the batch file to a safe place like c:\windows\system32

2) Download the Windows 2003 Resource kit and install it to a directory with NO spaces, not the default in “C:\Program Files”. Use C:\RESOURCEKIT, as I will use it for the rest of the document. This is very important for some programs, which don't understand the space in “C:\Program Files”, but not for others...to be safe, put it here.

3) Open a command prompt, and change to the directory where you installed the Windows 2003 resource kit, in this case, C:\RESOURCEKIT.

4) From that directory, install the script as a service with the following command “instsrv YourServiceName C:\RESOURCEKIT\srvany.exe.” without the quotes around it. You can name the service any reasonably not-too-long name you like, and this will appear in the Services.msc. This should return “The service was successfully added!” Next we have to configure the new YourServiceName service.

5) Open the Registry editor to the [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\YourServiceName] key.

6) Right-click on the YourServiceName key and do “New>Key” and name it Parameters (case sensitive).

7) Expand the new Parameters key and in the right pane right-click and do “New>String Value” and name it Application (case sensitive).

8) Double-click your new “Application” key and enter c:\windows\system32\YourBatchFileName.bat and save it. The service is now ready to run.

9) Test run it from within the Control Panel>Administrator Tools>Services MMC. You will see the service YourServiceName now listed and you can start it.

Here is a copy of my original article: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/Windows-Server-Networking/30399980/solution-to-have-a-persistent-vpn-start-automatically-on-boot.aspx

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. Pity I cannot up vote 100x ...

Comment: Stopping the service doesn't stop the web server. Can I make it work somehow so the web stops when the service is not running?

Comment: @Radek Probably not unless you can program your script to not only start but stop it conditionally. I have never tired it, but if you put conditions in the script to check and see if were stopped, then run the start portion of the script, and if running, then stop it. That issue is common with these types of ad-hock services.

Comment: In the alternative, you could just create a stop batch file and put it somewhere convenient, like the quick launch, for times you want to stop it in the middle of a session. If you are running XP pro, you could go into gpedit.msc, and you could also put the stop batch file in the system shutdown scripts, so it terminates cleanly on system shutdown.

Comment: I can use `taskkill /f /t /im ruby.exe` to stop the server but I do not know how to implement it in relation to to stopping the server from MMC. Do you know what the stop service do? does it run the service again with some parameter or so?

Comment: I need this 'stop' feature when I need to reload the server. So I need to stop it and load again ...

Comment: I created new question for that http://superuser.com/questions/301520/what-does-stop-service-do-in-windows

Comment: Installation of Windows 2003 Resource kit makes IBM Rational Functional Tester fail to open :-( Uninstalling makes it work....

Comment: @KCotreau: good news, the Resource kit doesn't have to be installed. It is good enough to extract two files `instsrv.exe` and `srvany.exe` You can update your steps, if you want to. 1) extract files from the downloaded file rktools.exe into let's say c:\temp directory `rktools /t:c:\temp\ /c` and then extract/copy two files we need from rktools.msi 7zip can do that job.

Comment: @Radek Wow, I believe you, but that is really strange. Yes, you only need those two tools, and only for the lenght of time it takes to create the service.

Comment: actually that is not correct. You need `instsrv.exe` to install the service but you need `srvany.exe` ALSO to run the service.

Comment: bit more of update. My script when running as a service makes IBM Rational Functional Tester not to work at all. Stopping (right now not sure if I have to reboot) makes RFT work again. Strange but true :-)