# what does STOP service do in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, ruby

I start my web server as web service on Windows XP. How it was done is described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/301457/how-to-run-script-as-a-windows-xp-service)

My web server is coded in ruby/sinatra and I start it `C:\Ruby187\bin\ruby c:\web\web2.rb`. That code the service too. Manually I stop the web server by pressing CTRL+C in the dos window if started from command line.

I admit that my ruby code is not 'specially written software' to be a service. But I'd like to know if I can shut it down somehow when I click stop button to this service.

How can I stop the server now as it started via service? I found out that I can stop it via `taskkill /f /t /im ruby.exe`

**Is there any way I can use the MMC stop service function to stop the web server?**

---

I call the web server directly like shown in the picture [click here to read the text in the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riPXg.png)

[image]

Comment: What is the batch file to start the Ruby server? Taskkill may not be the best way since it does just that: Kills the task, not really shutting it down cleanly. If I can see how you start it, I may be able to tell you how to stop it. I will have to look at it in the morning though...very late here.

Comment: That doesn't look like a Windows *Service*, these are applications specially written to be a service (installed as a service, using specific APIs to communicate with the Service Control Manager (SCM)). When something is a service is will appear in the services MMC snapin and can be controlled by the APIs the snapin uses (eg. `sc.exe` command line tool).

Comment: @Richard: To Windows, it *is* a service - *srvany* takes care of the SCM communication.

Answer (score 4):

The <kbd>Stop</kbd> button sends a "Stop service" control to the service's main program – in this case it's *srvany*. The rest is up to that program. And [it appears that *srvany* will simply ignore the control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424374/windows-srvany-exe-and-service-stop).

It seems that the version of *srvany* for Windows NT 4.0 *does* kill its immediate children – you can get it [from Microsoft](ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/bussys/winnt/winnt-public/reskit/nt40/i386/srvany_x86.exe).

It is possible to write a *real* Windows service that would stop your Ruby program nicely – for example, using Python's `win32serviceutil`. (There doesn't appear to be any Ruby module to interface with Windows, unfortunately.)

---

From command line or batch scripts, this will do the same as the Stop button:

- `sc stop <name>`
- `net stop <name>`

Programmatically, you need to call [`OpenSCManager(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684323(v=vs.85).aspx), [`OpenService(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684330(v=vs.85).aspx), then [`ControlService(..., SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682108(v=vs.85).aspx).